# How to get Geo location from the WebURL

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

- I have create one ASP.NET website and Hosted it on the server.
- Suppose My web access URL is `"www.xyz.com"`.
- Now I want the `Geo Location` who access my website and display it on the Google Map. Or can I get the `latitude` or `longitude` from where this Web-URL is access ?

So, is this possible ?

Comment: obtain the user’s location first from where the website accessed.

Comment: How can I get the user's location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is HTML CODE

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IPAddress" HeaderText="IP Address" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CountryName" HeaderText="Country" />    
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Latitude" HeaderText="Latitude" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Longitude" HeaderText="Latitude" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is C# Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
    {
        ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

    string APIKey = "<Your API Key>";
    string url = string.Format("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key={0}&ip={1}&format=json", APIKey, ipAddress);
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string json = client.DownloadString(url);
        Location location = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Location>(json);
        List<Location> locations = new List<Location>();
        locations.Add(location);
        gridView1.DataSource = locations;
        gridView1.DataBind();
    }
}


public class Location
{
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }      
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [HTML Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp). HTML Geolocation API is used to locate a user's position. you can get latitude && longitude !!
here my codes :

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    // support geolocation
    var success = function(position){
        latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log('here latitude :'+latitude+' && longitude :'+longitude);
    }
    var errors = function(){
        console.log('not working');
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, errors);
} else {
    alert('upgrade your browser !');
}
```

My out put is : here latitude :37.5030042 && longitude :127.0507571

## Edit

you want to see the all users Geo location who access your website.
i think two ways. Using google analytics api with google maps or use ajax(5sec update new geolocation data to html& your Database(mysql,dynamo,redis,etc..))

```
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
         // support geolocation
         var success = function(position){
             latitude = position.coords.latitude;
             longitude = position.coords.longitude;
             console.log('here latitude :'+latitude+' && longitude :'+longitude);

             setInterval(function(e){
                 $.ajax({
                   type: "get",
                   dataType: 'json',
                   url: 'here request url',
                   cache: false,
                   data: { // request user geo data
                       latitude : latitude,
                       longitude : longitude
                   }
                 }).done(function(xhr) {
                     if(xhr.status){
                         // response users geo data and update your html DOM
                         $('#maps').html(xhr.geo.datas)
                     }else{
                         alert(xhr.msg);
                     }
                 })
             },5000); // default 5 second
         }
         var errors = function(){
             console.log('not working');
         }
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, errors);

     } else {
         alert('upgrade your browser !');
     }
```

Comment: This is work for the single user. I want to see the all users Geo location who access my website

Comment: Using google analytics api with google maps or use ajax(5s update new geo datas)

Comment: @Chetan Sanghani Please check out this document [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=session)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this to obtain user's location:
Unless you set a timeout and error, your request to get the current position might never return.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var startPos;
  var geoOptions = {
  timeout: 10 * 1000
}

var geoSuccess = function(position) {
  startPos = position;
  document.getElementById('startLat').innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
  document.getElementById('startLon').innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;
};
var geoError = function(error) {
  console.log('Error occurred. Error code: ' + error.code);
  // error.code can be:
  //   0: unknown error
  //   1: permission denied
  //   2: position unavailable (error response from location provider)
  //   3: timed out
 };

   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, geoOptions);
 };
```

Comment: This is work for the single user. I want to see the all users Geo location who access my website

Comment: I want to display all the user's Geo location on same time,

Comment: Trying to store in a array but not able to test it.

Comment: so, How can I get the perfect result ?